# Determine HSL variation to transform a color in another one

Tags: colors, less, hsl

I use **LESS**, and I would like to take advantage by various integrated [color functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations) that allow to set only few basic colors, and then derive others changing *Hue, Saturation, Lightness, Spin,* ecc.

Let's imagine that we have the following 2 colors (a light-green and a dark-green in this example) in my colorizer:

```
@primary-color:    rgb(0,100,60);
@secondary-color:  rgb(185,215,50);
```

I would like to explicitly set only `@primary-color` and then *obtain* `@secondary-color` after an appropriate HSL transformation. (for example `darken(hsl(90, 80%, 50%), 20%`) )

Is there any way to determine **what hsl setting I have to apply to `@primary-color` in order to gain `@secondary-color`**?

In other words:

Given 2 RGB color definitions, is there any way to determine what difference in terms of *Hue*, *Saturation* and *Lightness*, exist between them, to express `@secondary-color` as a variations of `@primary-color`?

P.S.: maybe also with help of external tools like Photoshop, if necessary.

Comment: Finding the difference between the two is possible but I am bit confused by the question. To find the difference won't you have to specify two colors? If yes, why again to find secondary-color based on primary?

Comment: @Harry: this is a simplified case, but imagine a typical website colorizer, with many variation of green colors and gray colors. For example, currently I have website that utilize 4 types of "green" and 5 types of "gray". If I wish to change entire theme to "red and yellow varations" instead of actual "green and gray", I should change all 4 greens into 4 reds and all 5 grays into 5 yellows. Instead, if I could set each green varation as "derivation" of a basic one, I could change only this basic color to then obtian similar transformation on red tonalities. I hope that could be clearer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the way to calculate the difference between the hue, saturation and lightness values of two colors and then use it to calculate the second color based on the first.

The individual steps are as follows:

- **Color Difference Calculation:** Calculate the Hue, Saturation and Lightness differences between the two given colors by using the `hue()`, `saturation()` and `lightness()` functions. This function can be used separately just to output the differences alone.
- **Arriving at the secondary color based on primary:** This is a three step process and they are as follows:

  - Adjust the Hue of the primary color by using the `spin()` function by passing the hue difference between the two colors
  - Adjust the Saturation of the Hue Adjusted color (from previous step) by using the `saturate()` or `desaturate()` functions depending on the difference.
  - Adjust the Lightness of the Saturation Adjusted color (from previous step) by using the `darken()` or `lighten()` functions depending on the difference.

This answer is a Less adaptation of this [SASS Article](http://thesassway.com/advanced/how-to-programtically-go-from-one-color-to-another-in-sass) on how to calculate one color from another.

```css
@primary: rgb(0,100,60); /* primary color */
@secondary: rgb(185,215,50); /* secondary color */

/* mixin to calculate the difference between two given colors */
.color-diff(@color1; @color2){ 
    @hueDiff: hue(@color2) - hue(@color1);
    @saturationDiff: saturation(@color1) - saturation(@color2);
    @lightnessDiff: lightness(@color1)- lightness(@color2);

    color1: @color1; color2:@color2; /* just for testing, can be removed */
}

/* Step 1: mixin to adjust the hue difference between the colors */
.adjust-hue(@color; @diff){ 
    @hueAdjusted: spin(@color, @hueDiff);
}

/* Step 2: mixin to adjust the saturation difference */
.adjust-saturation(@color; @diff) when (@diff > 0){
    @satAdjusted: desaturate(@color, abs(@diff)); /* desaturate if diff is greater than 0 */
}
.adjust-saturation(@color; @diff) when not (@diff > 0){
    @satAdjusted: saturate(@color, abs(@diff)); /* saturate if diff is not greater than 0 */
}

/* Step 3: mixin to adjust the lightness diff between the colors */
.adjust-lightness(@color; @diff) when (@diff > 0){
    @lightnessAdjusted: darken(@color, abs(@diff)); /* darken if diff is greater than 0 */
}
.adjust-lightness(@color; @diff) when not (@diff > 0){
    @lightnessAdjusted: lighten(@color, abs(@diff)); /* else lighten */
}

div{
    .color-diff(@primary; @secondary);
    .adjust-hue(@primary; @hueDiff);
    .adjust-saturation(@hueAdjusted; @saturationDiff);
    .adjust-lightness(@satAdjusted; @lightnessDiff);
    color: @lightnessAdjusted; /* final output value */
}
```

**Compiled CSS:**

```
div {
    color1: #00643c;
    color2: #b9d732;
    color: #b9d732;
}
```

---

If you would just wish to obtain the differences between two colors, then you could use a loop like below to output the differences in terms of hue, saturation and lightness values.

```css
@color-list-1: rgb(0,100,60), #B0BCA7, #ABCDEF; /* list of primary colors */
@color-list-2: rgb(185,215,50), #BADA55, #FEDCBA; /* list of secondary colors */

#output{
    .loop-colors(@index) when (@index > 0){
        @primary: extract(@color-list-1, @index);
        @secondary: extract(@color-list-2, @index);
        .color-diff(@primary; @secondary);

        /* output the values of the comparison */
        color-comparison-@{index}+: ~"Hue Difference: @{hueDiff}";
        color-comparison-@{index}+: ~"Saturation Difference: @{saturationDiff}";        
        color-comparison-@{index}+: ~"Lightness Difference: @{lightnessDiff}";
        .loop-colors(@index - 1);
    }
    .loop-colors(length(@color-list-1));
}
```

The above code will compare the corresponding values in both lists and output their difference like below:

```css
#output {
  color-comparison-3: Hue Difference: -180, Saturation Difference: -29.142857142857153%, Lightness Difference: -5.882352941176478%;
  color-comparison-2: Hue Difference: -19.849624060150404, Saturation Difference: -50.70282063269439%, Lightness Difference: 10.196078431372548%;
  color-comparison-1: Hue Difference: -85.09090909090908, Saturation Difference: 32.65306122448979%, Lightness Difference: -32.352941176470594%;
}
```

Comment: mhmmm very interesting, but my question was supposed to have an easier answer. Obviously, I could use your code to calculate variations, but problem "speaking with words" would be: "Ok, I have this rgb(x,y,z) (or equivalent hsl() definition ) color.
I would like its darker variation which should be equivalent to hsl(a,b,c). How to obtain these varations, also with a dedicated tool, in order to gain values to be set in LESS Color functions?

Comment: @LucaDetomi: I get your point. But (a) I don't know of any such tool because I really haven't had the need for them yet and (b) if you are asking for a tool, the question is likely to get closed as off-topic. To obtain the variations when two colors are given, you would just need the `color-diff` mixin. It would give you what is the difference between two given colors.