# less coloring functions lighten(),darken()

Tags: css, colors, less

I have these basic colors

```
@_orange: #f4a534; 
@_red: #ff0000;
@_green-dark: #328e3e;
@_green: #54bb62;
```

and I would like to use less functions

> lighten() , darken(), saturate() ,mix()

to generate this color `#ffe082`  out of @_orange ,

how can I know the output color and what I need to do to produce this color with these functions ?

Thanks !

Comment: When you know the final color that you want wouldn't it be a lot more easier to just use it than write some logic to find what function should be applied, what values should be passed to it and then produce the final color using that function and values?

Comment: okay , I have to follow these basic colors , and use less functions to produce any change .. is it possible to do so ?

Comment: You're overcomplicating things buddy. Have a predefined function (something of your choice, like say lighten 10% or darken 20% etc), apply it on the basic colors and use whatever output it gives you rather than trying to find a logic to get a very specific color.

Comment: @Harry I'm requested to follow this , stick to basic colors ,yet I have a design with this very specific color , got me ?

Comment: In sass there have a online tool for checking it http://sassme.arc90.com/

Comment: I suppose this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314009. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698726, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223412 etc.

Comment: @sisimh, If you already know the required orange `#ffe082` why do you need to apply Sass functions to `@_orange`, to calculate the value. We generally use Sass functions where we want a respective lighter/darker/etc gradient of a color.